# How to type like a Human via ActionChains key_down, key_up

Tags: python, selenium

I am making an online automation program. Unfortunately, however, this site checks the user's input speed.

The site reports an error message due to two reasons: the speed at which the key is pressed and the speed at which the key is pressed. Therefore, the commonly used send_keys are not available. This is because the key_up speed is displayed as 0 when debugging.

To solve this problem, it seems necessary to adjust the speed of input like a person. So I tried the following.

```
ac = ActionChains(driver)
ac.key_down("a")
ac.perform()
Sleep(0.010, 0.05)

ac = ActionChains(driver)
ac.key_up("a")
ac.perform()
Sleep(0.010, 0.05)
```

I would appreciate if you could tell me a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through string :

```
for i in "somehting fad a":
    time.sleep(1)
    elem.send_keys(i)
```

If that doesn't work try :

```
for i in "This is a test":
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(i).pause(1).key_up(i).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
```

There is pause method within action class that pauses next action in the chain

Comment: @Deluxe could you add the link to the website

Comment: @Deluxe updated the answer , see if the updated answer